# Steam doesn't work after update nvidia drivers Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, steam

I had nvidia-450 drivers and all worked fine.
Today I updated my OS, and steam doesn't work after this.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/ilys/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam -nominidumps -nobreakpad
[2021-06-16 16:28:49] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2021 05:25:53
[2021-06-16 16:28:49] Opted in to client beta 'publicbeta' via beta file
You are in the 'publicbeta' client beta.
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  46
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
```

So i reinstalled all new drivers

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460 --reinstall`
sudo apt install nvidia-dkms-460 --reinstall
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460 --reinstall
sudo apt install libnvidia-common-460 --reinstall

nvidia-smi
Wed Jun 16 16:33:46 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P8     7W /  N/A |    433MiB /  6069MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1348      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2119      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                117MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2287      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                  36MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2295      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell               60MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2773      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          171MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I read in one topic run with STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 20.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is disabled by the user
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpipewire-0.3.so.0
```

I have all this packages

Reinstalled steam.
But nothing helped. I don't know what I should to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known bug as reported in [Steam-for-Linux](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7067).

I am wondering why you use the 460 drivers, while 465 drivers are available. However, try to install the  following lib

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460:i386
```

Otherwise check the apt-policy

```
apt-cache policy libnvidia-gl-460 libnvidia-gl-460:i386
```

If that doesn't work install the new drivers from the following ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465 libnvidia-gl-465 libnvidia-gl-465:i386
```

Beside the way, it's clever to reinstall steam.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't this repo sudo apt install nvidia-driver-465 libnvidia-gl-465 libnvidia-gl-465:i386, so i couldn't install libnvidia-gl-460:i386 :)